# Java Request and HTTP Request equivalent in LoadRunner

Tags: java, http, jmeter, loadrunner

Which protocol can I use in LoadRunner to convert a JMeter script which have both Java Request and HTTP request?

The Java request accept parameters and the class generate the token id which is used in the HTTP request for the authentication of REST services with body data (JSON).

Comment: Removed tags from title; trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Web Virtual user with Java Language